# what is "upstream" in git push and pull command

Tags: git, svn, repository

I am working with github repsitories but have bit confusion in `origin` & `upstream`;

and tell me if I am working in BRANCH_B then is there any need to add `origin` keyword to pull or push?

```
$ git pull upstream master
```

Answer (score 4):

`origin` and `upstream` are names of remotes.

You can create and list them with `git remote`.

`origin` is the default remote created when you `git clone` and it's the one used when you omit an explicit remote in most commands.

I guess `upstream` is just another remote name created as an example.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, they're just usual names for remotes. `origin` is your "main" remote, `upstream` is the remote to original repo (assuming yours is a fork).

Comment: and assuming someone already created that fork/repo for you.  I guess they sometimes use 'upstream' as an example repo name.  But obviously, this seems more confusing, because I also thought 'upstream' was a Git keyword.  I also remember PHP examples where they use variables named 'php', and I wasn't sure if 'php' was part of the language that I had to use, or if it was just an example.

Comment: In general, when writing documentation for X, do not use examples that seem like they are part of X.  Instead, use example names about horses or ice cream or anything else a 4-year-old could understand.  Names that clearly have nothing to do with X.